# neo4j MATCH ... CREATE UNIQUE in version 2.0

Tags: graph, neo4j, unique, cypher

I'm running neo4j version 2.0.0 (on Mac OSX with JDK7). The documentation has many examples of how to use CREATE UNIQUE with MATCH. I can't get any of them to work, but the old method of doing CREATE UNIQUE works as its documented in 1.9 (with START). The MATCH query doesn't throw an error, it just doesn't create any nodes and doesn't return any nodes. On the neo4j doc website, if I click 'try this live' it works, but I can't recreate that.

I'm able to create nodes normally, run normal queries, and so far haven't noticed any other odd behavior.

this doesn't work for me:

```
MATCH (a { name: 'A' })
CREATE UNIQUE (a)-[:KNOWS]-(c:blue)
RETURN c
```

but this works as expected:

```
START root=node(0)
CREATE UNIQUE root-[:X]-(leaf {name:'D'} )
RETURN leaf
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a node with `name:'A'`? This query is an exact translation to `match` searching for node(0). It assumes you have a node(0), though.

```
MATCH (a)
WHERE id(a) = 0
CREATE UNIQUE (a)-[:KNOWS]->(c:blue)
RETURN c
```

Try just `MATCH (a {name:'A'}) RETURN a;`, and if it doesn't return anything, that's why the `CREATE UNIQUE` isn't creating anything.

Comment: Thank you. The issue was my understanding of how this worked. I think the documentation is a bit misleading, or maybe I assumed too much. "If the pattern described needs a node, and it can’t be matched, a new node will be created." This leaves out the fact that it still must match the MATCH condition.